# person is eligible to play on the team

Tags: python

problem=A soccer team is looking for girls from ages 10 to 12 to play on their team. Write a program to ask the user’s age and whether the user is male or female (using “m” or “f”). Display a message indicating whether the person is eligible to play on the team. but Make the program so that it doesn’t ask for the age unless the user is a girl.

here is my code

```
name=raw_input("Enter ur name ")
gender=raw_input("Enter ur gender ")
if gender=="f":
    age=float(raw_input("enter ur age "))
if 10<= age <=12:
    print "ur eligible"
elif gender=="m":
     print "male not allowed"
else :
    print "ur not eligible"
```

Comment: when i enter girl in withing age limit output is correct but when i enter "m" for male gender it shows error saying that "age is not defined "

Comment: Just think through your conditional logic... why do you test `if 10 <= age <= 12:` if the person is `m`?

Comment: If you enter `"m"` it never goes through the first if statement which is where you defined age. When it skips that and goes through the second condition age is indeed not defined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3149020/spencer-wieczorek how to correct it? i yet to understand where i made a mistake on understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few quick points I noticed:

1.Indentation issue for the if statement in the age condition.
This if statement should ideally be within the if statement of gender==f.

2. The way python requires you to write/use "and" condition. You can look at the syntax here https://www.learnpython.org/en/Conditions
3. If someone enters an age out of the range required, there should be display on the screen such as female but not eligible.
4. Its always good to introduce certain print statements as part of debugging to see how/where your code is reaching upto while executing.

The below piece of code should help

```
name=input("Enter ur name ")
gender=input("Enter ur gender ")
if gender=="f":
    age=float(input("enter ur age "))
    if age <=12 and age >=10:
        print ("ur eligible")
    else:
        print("female but not eligible"              )
elif gender=="m":
     print ("male not allowed")
```

Comment: please share where i exactly  made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

It is just an indentation problem. 
You should add also an else inside the first if in case you want show that a girl without the correct age is not elegible. Finally, you could want change the last message to show that a sex different to f or m is not valid.

```
name=raw_input("Enter ur name ")
gender=raw_input("Enter ur gender ")
if gender=="f":
    age=float(raw_input("enter ur age "))
    if 10<= age <=12:
        print "ur eligible"
    else:
        print "ur not eligible"
elif gender=="m":
     print "male not allowed"
else:
    print 'gender should be "m" (male) or "f" (female)'
```

Comment: just try to run this code: name=any girl name,gender=f, age=7(any age below the limit" and RUN it, you get out put nothing i just tried it

Comment: Yeah of course, y let the final else out of the first if, I'll update my answer

Comment: great it works can you point out where i made the mistake? thanks